# Unable to install flutter IOS app on non development IOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am working on a Flutter application. I am able to build the release version of my app without any issue, but for iOS when I use DIAWI to give a link to any other user with Enterprise distribution the installation will not complete. We have an unfocused icon on the device and clicking it will do nothing.

Comment: If you are sharing a build using DIAWI, UDID must be added to the profile you are using to build the IPA.

Comment: but I have done like this without adding UDID before. strangeness of the problem is once I have run the app using xcode on the wired connected device it will install from diawi without any issue.

Comment: but I will check after adding UDID of the devices. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I tried adding the UDID and I still have the same issue. My provisioning profile is of universal type so I think adding UDID to the registered device will not help me.

Comment: You can't share via diawi using universal type of profile..

Comment: Thanks for the help Krish. I was able resolve the issue. the Runner.app generated through flutter build ios cant be used for this purpose.You have to use Product > Archive which will use the Scheme select in Xcode. So before using this you have change the scheme or generate a new scheme with release mode selected. This will allow the system to use Enterprise Distribution Profile and give you .ipa file generated automatically at iso>Runner>"selected folder" Using this .ipa there was no issue installing the app on any IOS device using diawi. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Krish. I was able resolve the issue. the Runner.app generated through flutter build ios cant be used for this purpose.You have to use Product > Archive which will use the Scheme select in Xcode. So before using this you have change the scheme or generate a new scheme with release mode selected. This will allow the system to use Enterprise Distribution Profile and give you .ipa file generated automatically at iso>Runner>"selected folder" Using this .ipa there was no issue installing the app on any IOS device.